# Game theory - Proof of the folk theorem

Tags: proof-explanation, game-theory

I am trying to understand the proof for the [folk theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Folk_theorem_(game_theory)#Infinitely-repeated_games_without_discounting) for infinitely repeated games without discounting (average reward).

The proof says that given that a rewarding payoff is enforceable and feasible, then the state must be a Nash equilibrium.

It also says that if a state is a Nash equilibrium, then the payoff should be enforceable, but that's easy to prove.

For the first statement, they do a proof by construction, which can be found [here](https://www.cs.ubc.ca/%7Ekevinlb/teaching/cs532a%20-%202003-4/folk.pdf). I understood till the part where the reward payoff of the player $i$ is $r_i$.

Now as a part of the construction, the state that the players will use a grim strategy, and if anyone diverges from the agreed upon strategy, then all the other players will play the minimax strategy for the player who diverged. So the payoff of the person will be less or equal to $r_i$, because earlier, the payoff was enforceable.

Understood.

But what I don't understand is, how can they assume that a grim strategy would be played by the other players? What if they don't enforce this strategy? What if, the other players just didn't react to what the diverger did, when the game earlier was enforceable and was feasible?

Since this condition is missing from the proof, I don't totally understand how this works. Any pointers appreciated.

Comment: Not precise enough to be an answer, but the punishment is credible because the min-max is a Nash equilbrium period by period, whereas the higher payoff is not.

Comment: @Trurl Didn't quite get you. Isn't min-max a nash equilibrium only in a case of zero sum games? As mentioned [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimax#In_zero-sum_games).

Comment: Two points: in the models I'm most familiar with, Oligopoly models, the threat point is the single-shot Nash equilibrium forever, and if everyone plays that on a deviation, then it is self-enforcing-- you will do worse if everyone is playing Nash and you don't. Second, good point, that is why the article talks about subgame perfect equilibrium. Subgame perfection answers the question of whether it is individual's interest to enforce the strategy.